# How do I keep CPU from going into Turbo mode when I run VirtualBox in Windows?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

PC Info:

- Windows 8.1
- Intel i7-4710HQ 2.5GHz
- 16 GB memory
- NVidio GTX 860 (2 GB mem)

Virtual OS Settings:

Ubuntu 14.04 64bit desktop

Memory: 2048 Kb

2 (of 8) Processors , Enable PAE, Acceleration Enabled

Video Mem: 128 Mb

Execution cap: 40%

CPU running at 3.2 - 3.5 GHz

Comment: Curious, why do you want to do this? I worry that you are asking how to do x bit actually want to do y.

Comment: I want to keep the chip clock speed <= 2.5 GHz to avoid higher temp / power consumption. Right now I'm trying Maximum processor state = 90% in Power Options > Processor power management.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be a limitation of VirtualBox itself. When you start the Virtual Machine it "reserves" those 2/8 cores (even though it didn't need them for a child process).